# How to extract keypoints with confidence score from a pytorch output tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, pose-estimation

I am using a pretrained model for pose estimation with Pytorch:
https://github.com/microsoft/human-pose-estimation.pytorch

I am using the model to detect persons and their 17 keypoints in an image but I am not sure how I should convert the output tensor to a format of pixel coordinates for each keypoint with a confidence score for each person.

This is the code for the prediction:

```
model.eval()
img_t = ToTensor()(img).unsqueeze(0)
out = model(img_t)
out.shape
```

The output shape is [1, 16, 64, 56]. I am a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of tensor? What are the unique values? What was the shape of input tensor?